# what is the name of this matrix? does it have any special characteristics?

Tags: matrices, inverse

does anyone know the name of this matrix or if it has any special characteristics or how to calculate its inverse efficiently e.g. in a closed-form?

[                \begin{array}{llllll}
                    a_{11} & a_{12}& a_{13} & a_{14}  & \dots & a_{1L} \\
                    q_1 & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{23} & \dots & a_{2L} \\
                    q_2 & q_1 & a_{33} & a_{34} & \dots & a_{3L} \\
                    q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & a_{44} & \dots & a_{3L} \\
                    q_4 & q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & \dots & a_{3L} \\
                    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
                    q_L & q_{L-1} & q_{L-2} & q_{L-3} & \dots  & a_{LL}\\
                  \end{array}]

hint: the lower triangle consists of diagonals with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

This matrix is not always invertible, e.g. if $a_{i,j} = 0$ for every $i,j$ or if $a_{i,j}=q_i=c$ for every $i,j$.

Anyway you may recognize the structure of a [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) on the lower triangle.